# Alternative to deprecated method DataStream.keyBy()

Tags: apache-flink

On Flink 1.11 [DataStream API page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html), there is a **WindowWordCount** program which uses **keyBy()**, however, this method is deprecated, I couldn't find any examples as to how to rewrite it without using **keyBy()**. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

I use Intellij; it warns keyBy() is deprecated. This is the only [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17074) I could find.

Comment: i cant even imagine that keyBy() is deprecated as this is one of the most used functions. where this info is coming from?

Comment: updated the description with the link

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've created [FLINK-18797](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18797) to track getting the docs and examples updated.

Comment: Thank you!  It would be helpful the documents are up today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forms of keyBy that take an Integer or String parameter have been deprecated. You should use the form of keyBy that takes a KeySelector function -- e.g., replace

```java
stream.keyBy("id")
```

with

```java
stream.keyBy(event -> event.id)
```

and replace

```java
streamOfTuples.keyBy(0)
```

with

```java
streamOfTuples(tuple -> tuple.f0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look.  I am rather new to Flink, and not familiar with KeySelector function.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me out of a bind a few days ago.
May I ask How would would that Syntax behave when trying to use keyBy with several parameters?
I've tried returning a tuple2, but the function I'm concatenating (window) expects 2 arguments instead of a tuple.