# Flink KeyBy fields

Tags: java, apache-flink, deprecated

I am trying to use the keyby function with a given field, however, IntelliJ is telling me that this option is deprecated.

```java
// map each job event to a 2-tuple
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, Long>> mappedEvents =  events.map(new AppendOneMapper()).slotSharingGroup("2");

// group the stream of tuples by jobId
KeyedStream<Tuple2<Long, Long>, Tuple> keyedEvents = mappedEvents.keyBy(0);
```

How would I use new methods to correctly do this?

Comment: For how to handle keyBy with tuples, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63219684/2000823.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KeyBy with integers or strings is deprecated.
From documentation: "Deprecated. Use keyBy(KeySelector)."

```
org.apache.flink.api.java.functions
Interface KeySelector<IN,KEY>
Type Parameters:
IN - Type of objects to extract the key from.
KEY - Type of key.
```

KeySelector is a functional interface, so you can just plug in lambda expression.

Replace

```
.keyBy(key)
```

With

```
.keyBy(event -> event.getKey())
```